# Saving $stateParams while refreshing a $state - UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-router and I have few stateparams in my state, but while I refresh the page the stateparams are going undefined. How I can maintain the stateparam even when we refresh.

Answer (score -1):

You should store any parameter from your state inside of localstorage.

```
cache.$inject = ['$localStorage', '$cookieStore', 'CONFIG', 'CONSTANT'];

export function cache($localStorage, $cookieStore, CONFIG: IAppConfig, CONSTANT) {
    return {
           storeState: function (state) {
            $localStorage.state = state;
           }
    }
}
```

this sample code written typescript.

Comment: OP asked help with angularJS, code written in javascript. The provided answer was for angular2+, example written in typescript. If possible, provide snippet for angularJS written in ES5 or ES6